# Logging only the command output to a file

Tags: ssh, expect

I want to log the output of a few commands that I run in an expect SSH spawn script, but I want the output to be pretty clean. I already found some info on the internet regarding logging, but it does not work except for sending the command into the log file.

---Starting in the middle of the script, here are my steps---

```
expect -re ">" 

log_file "settings.txt";

send_user "show device\n"

expect -re ">"

log_file "rules.txt";

send "show access-rules\n"

expect -re ">"

log_file "interfaces.txt";

send "show interface all\n"

expect -re ">"

log_file "cfs.txt";

send "show tsr content-filtering\n"

expect -re ">"

log_file "routes.txt";

send "show routes\n"

expect -re ">"

log_file "nat.txt";

send "show nat\n"

expect -re ">"

send "exit\n"
```

The `send_user` command, only sends the command to the log file as does the `send_log` command. I only want the output of that command sent to the log file, the command itself is also allowed in the log.

Comment: You want to send the logs only to file not to `stdout` ?

Comment: Only to files yes. later in the script, i curl those files to sharepoint, so it should be pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is to suppress the output of `send` command which is basically explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804176/974155). (I guess that is your requirement. Only write the output of command, not the command.)

Since `log_user` and `log_file` bounded tightly when it comes to logging into the file, we have to tweak it with `send_log`.

A basic idea can be generalized as

```
# We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
# The second dollar sign is meant to match the end of a line
set prompt "#|>|\\\$$"  
log_file output.log
send "show command here\r"
log_user 0
expect -re "\r\n(.*)$prompt"; # match actual command output
log_user 1
send_log "$expect_out(1,string)"; # Sending it to the log file
```

Now, as per your requirement, you want to send it to separate files for each command. You can define the commands and file names for those commands output in a separate list.

```
spawn ssh <host> <port>
# Further your logic to handle the login

proc getCmdOutput {cmd} {
 global cmdsList logFileList
 set prompt "#|>|\\\$$"; 
 # Finding the log file name based on the 'cmd' passed
 log_file -noappend [lindex $logFileList [lsearch $cmdsList $cmd]]
 send "$cmd\r"
 log_user 0
 expect -re "\r\n(.*)$prompt"
 log_user 1
 send_log "$expect_out(1,string)"; # Sending command output to file
 log_file; # Removing logging of file.
}


set cmdsList {
        "show version"
        "show interfaces"
        "show services"
        "show vlan"
}

set logFileList {
        version.log
        interfaces.log
        services.log
        vlan.log
}


foreach cmd $cmdsList {
        getCmdOutput $cmd
}
```

Please note that the list `cmdsList` and `logFileList` should be homologous to each other in terms of the commands and corresponding log file name.