# How to turn off stderr in Expect script or stop "Connection to ... closed" message after exiting?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

So I have been trying to learn bash scripting with expect and I'm running into an annoying problem where even after I turn off output by setting log_user to 0, the logout message for when I exit the ssh server is still printed as "logout
Connection to blah.blah.blah closed". Going the hackish way and issuing the exit command inside the script to expect is undesirable, and neglects to print a new line in the terminal, leaving an unsightly terminal prompt behind. How do I suppress or turn off this connection closed message in my expect script? Here's a template of the code for my expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#-f flag tells expect to read commands from file

# Set Password Prompt and Password
set PASSP "password:"
set PASSW "your_password_here\n"

# Set SFTP Prompt 
set SFTP "sftp> "

# Set Remote Prompt and Project Directories
# The GL server is super weird, so make sure RPROMPT ends in the
# name of the project compilation directory and PROJDIR is the 
# relative path (from home but without the tilde) of the main 
# project directory.

set RPROMPT "projdir_here]"
set PROJDIR "path_to_projdir_here"

# Set SSH Address
set ADDRESS your_username_here@your_address_here

# Annoying long output turned off
log_user 0

send_user "Logging in...\n"

spawn sftp $ADDRESS
expect $PASSP
send $PASSW

expect $SFTP
send_user "Uploading necessary files...\n"

send "cd $PROJDIR\n"
expect $SFTP
send "put *.cpp .\n"
expect $SFTP
send "put *.h .\n"
expect $SFTP
send "put Makefile .\n"
expect $SFTP
send "exit\n"

spawn ssh $ADDRESS
expect $PASSP
send $PASSW
expect "]"
send "cd $PROJDIR\n"

expect $RPROMPT
send_user "Cleaning remote directory...\n"

send "make clean\n"

# Output turned on temporarily so compiler feedback can be determined
expect $RPROMPT
log_user 1
send_user "Compiling on server...\n"

send "make\n"

# Turn off output and submit (this assumes that your makefile has a 'submit'
# target with the command to submit your file there)
expect $RPROMPT
log_user 0
send_user "\nSubmitting Requisite Files...\n"

send "make submit\n"

expect $RPROMPT
send_user "Quitting...\n"

# I can't figure out how to turn off stderr in expect so that an annoying 'connection closed' 
# message is printed even the log_user has been set to 0
send "logout\n"

# Transfer control to user
interact
```

You can see that at the end of the program, before I use the interact command, that the offending message is printed after "logout\n" is sent and the connection to the server is closed. This happens despite log_user being set to 0 above. How on earth do I turn off stderr output inside my script? I've even looked at the manual pages for expect at [expect man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) but there didn't seem to be much useful there. I don't understand how to turn off stderr inside an expect script so that this message isn't printed, help would be much appreciated! I really just want the script to be quiet when I'm logging out. Because it's pretty obvious that I issued a logout command, I'm not sure why this output goes to stderr. Is there a command in ssh that won't output a "Connection to...closed" message when the user exits? It would be better if I could just pipe stderr to oblivion or suppress it somehow. The normal ways don't seem to work because this is an expect script.

Comment: After sending `logout` command, connection will be closed, Then how user can interact with ?

Comment: Dinesh, you are correct I should simply put 'exit' instead. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just the incorrect use of `log_user`. It should be used as,

```
log_user 0
send "logout\r"  
expect eof
log_user 1
```

Note that I am expecting for `eof` pattern after sending `logout\r`, because it will lead to the closure of the connection. Always use `\r` in place of `\n` while using the `send` command.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804176/974155) to know more about the `log_user` to suppress the output.

Instead of having a prompt to defined as a static string, it can be generalized as,

```
# We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$' 
# The last dollar sign represents line-end.
set prompt "#|>|%|\\\$ $";
```

While the expect is used, we have to accompany with -re flag to specify that as a regular expression.

```
expect -re $prompt
```

**SshDemo.exp**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
set prompt "#|>|\\\$ $"
spawn ssh dinesh@myserver
expect {
        "(yes/no)" { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
        "password"
}
send "welcome123\r"
expect -re $prompt 
# Simply executing 'ls -l' command...
send "ls -l\r"
expect -re $prompt
log_user 0
send "logout\r"
expect eof
log_user 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my new, improved script based on the suggestions above. I also decided to use scp instead of sftp because it's much more concise and I'm only uploading files.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#-f flag tells expect to read commands from file

# Set Password Prompt and Password
set PASSP "password: "
set PASSW "your_password_here"

# Set Remote Prompt and Project Directories
# The ssh server is super weird, so make sure PROJDIR is the 
# directory name of the main project directory and PATH is
# the relative path to the project directory from home (with the tilde)

set PROJDIR "your_projdir_name_here"
set PATH "your_projdir_path_here"

# Set SSH Address
set ADDRESS your_username_here@source_hostname_here

# Turn off annoying output
log_user 0

send_user "Logging in and uploading necessary files...\n"

# upload files via scp, (shows upload prompt for user, concise)
spawn bash -c "scp *.cpp *.h Makefile $ADDRESS:$PATH"
expect $PASSP 
send "$PASSW\r"

interact

spawn ssh $ADDRESS
expect $PASSP
send "$PASSW\r"
expect "]"
send "cd $PATH\r"

expect "$PROJDIR]"
send_user "\nCleaning remote directory...\n"

send "make clean\r"

# Output turned on temporarily so compiler feedback can be determined
expect "$PROJDIR]"
log_user 1
send_user "Compiling on server...\n\n"

send "make\r"

# Turn off output and submit (this assumes that your makefile has a 'submit'
# target with the command to submit your file there)
expect "$PROJDIR]"
log_user 0
send_user "\n\nSubmitting Requisite Files...\n"

send "make submit\r"

expect "$PROJDIR]"
send_user "Quitting...\n"

send "logout\r"
expect eof

# Exit
exit
```