# Send command output in shell expect

Tags: expect

Following is the code I'm trying to execute with expect in shell script.

```
send "date +%d%m%y \n"  
set date1 "$expect_out(buffer)"  
puts "$date1"  
expect "#"
```

The output I'm getting is

```
date +%d%m%y  
111217
```

Is there any way to suppress the command(date +%d%m%y) and only store the output in variale date1?

Comment: your code does not work for me. please post a [mcve].

Comment: @emily, you realize this is [tag:expect] code, right?

Comment: yes it's obvious it's expect code. but there's no `expect` statement so i'm wondering how did the OP get the `$expect_out(buffer)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803188/how-to-suppress-expect-send-output

Answer (score 0):

Try this: expect to see 6 digits as a whole word

```tcl
send "date +%d%m%y\r"         ;# typically we use \r to "hit enter"
expect -re {\m(\d{6})\M}
set date1 "$expect_out(1,string)"  
puts "$date1"  
expect "#"
```

More generally, to select the text between the first line (the command) and the last line (the prompt), you can do:

```
lassign [regexp -inline {.*?\n(.*)\r\n#} $expect_out(buffer)] _ date1
```

where `_` is a throw-away variable that will hold the entire matching text of the regex, and `date1` will hold only the captured text.

See https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm for Tcl regex syntax.

---

Without `lassign`, you could write

```
regexp {.*?\n(.*)\r\n#} $expect_out(buffer) _ date1
```

Comment: lassign is not working in my system. Is there any other way to get only the output of the command?